# Java pattern repeated Capturing Groups

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

I have the following String

```
52x10x20x30x40
```

The string can be extended but with the same pattern and there will be other strings on both sides of it: for example

```
"Hello something 52x10x20x30x40 bla bla bla"
```

i want to capture all 2-digits.

I have the following regex

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d)([x]\\d\\d)+");
```

But with this regex i only get the following groups:

```
1: 52
2: x40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
"52x10x20x30x40".split("x");
```

?

> Forgot to mention that there can be other strings on both sides.

You could search for `"\\d{2}(x\\d{2})+"`, and use `split("x")` on the match.

Comment: Forgot to mention that there can be other strings on both sides

Comment: @Jonas: You could search for `"\\d{2}(x\\d{2})+"`, and use `split()` on the match.

Answer (score 0):

Regex doesn't support variable group lengths.

Use a split method instead, e.g. [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s `Splitter`:

```
Iterable<String> tokens = Splitter.on('x').split(str);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that there can be other strings on both sides

Comment: @Jonas well then you'll have to get rid of those first. Perhaps you'll first search for the pattern `(\\d\\d)(([x]\\d\\d)+)` and then split `matcher.group()`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to capture all two digit numbers you could use this expression:

```
(?<!\d)(\d\d)(?!\d)
```

Usually you can only get the last substring that a repeated capturing group matches. (.NET regex differs in this regard.)